# Vue 3 datepicker Element-Plus

Tags: datepicker, vue-component, vuejs3, element-plus

Im currently trying to display price (loaded via an api) under the days of a datepicker (a bit like google flights).

Exemple:
[image]

Im currently using Vue 3. Im trying to acheive this using Element-plus library. I can't find a way how to do it. Any suggestion (i checked Element-plus doc), or suggestion may another Vue 3 lib does exactly the same !

Here's my code

```
<link href="//unpkg.com/element-plus/lib/theme-chalk/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-plus/lib/index.full.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container-medium">
    <div id="app">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="block"><span class="demonstration">Single</span>
                <el-date-picker :default-value="new Date(2021, 6, 28)"
                                placeholder="Pick a date"
                                type="date"
                                :disabled-date="disabledDate"
                                v-model="value1"></el-date-picker>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var Main = {
        data() {
            return {
                value1: '',
                value2: '',
                disabledDate(time) {
                    return time.getTime() < Date.now()
                },
            };
        }
    };
    ;const app = Vue.createApp(Main);
    app.use(ElementPlus);
    app.mount("#app")
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the DatePicker has no slot for days. So, you cannot do it straight way. You can make a request do add it here https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last version of Element+ ([v1.2.0-beta.1](https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/releases/tag/1.2.0-beta.1)) they have added a new #cell slot in the DatePicker component.

Docs: [DatePicker - Custom content](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/date-picker.html#custom-content)

```
 <template #default="cell">
    <div class="cell" :class="{ current: cell.isCurrent }">
      <span class="text">{{ cell.text }}</span>
      <span v-if="isHoliday(cell)" class="holiday"></span>
    </div>
  </template>
```

[image: Screenshot of Custom content slot]

So, you can do it now with Element+ also.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I went with v-calendar, and injecting the content in the "date", everytime the "month panel" had finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PrimeVue [Calendar component](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/calendar). It has a **date** slot:

```
<Calendar id="datetemplate" v-model="date_with_price">
    <template #date="slotProps">
        {{slotProps.date.day}}<br>
        {{slotProps.date.price}}
    </template>
</Calendar>
```